# syntax analysis of expression!!

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a question.
Given the following grammar:
$$S \to ABC$$
$$A \to aA| \varnothing$$
$$B \to bB|a$$
$$C \to bCb|aCb|\varnothing$$

I found that its Chomsky form is:
$$S \to AS'|BC|AB|VB|a$$
$$S' \to BC$$
$$A \to UA'|UU$$
$$A' \to AU$$
$$B \to VB|b$$
$$C \to VC'|UC'|VV|UV$$
$$C' \to CV$$
$$U \to a$$
$$V \to b$$}

I want to make a syntax analysis of the expression $aabaaabb$.
But...how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive *aabaaabb*, first note that all the expression produced with your second and third rule must end by *a*, so an expression ending with *b* is necessarily an otcome of rule S or C (and in the former case one of the operands or rule S is already a non-empty outcome of rule C).

In general, you can find the general expression for, say expressions of type "A", that are (possibly empty) sequences of *a*, of type "B", which are possibly empty sequences of *b* followed by exactly one *a*, and of type $C$, which are even sequences of letters where the second half are all *b*.

Your expression is not of type C so it's an S = ABC, where A is *aa*, B is *ba* and C is *aabb*.

Of course you have to prove that this is the only possible derivation, but this is quite simple.

Comment: Nice...Thank you very much!!!

Comment: As an example of expression with multiple possible derivation, take $babbbb$. It can be derived by three applications of C: $∅→_Cbb→_Cabbb→_Cbabbbb$, and by using $S=(∅)(ba)(bbbb)$ where $a→_Bba$ and $∅→_Cbb→_Cbbbb$.